# Extract points from a path

Tags: qt

Using QPainterPath, I've constructed a graph (path), drew it, but now I need query the graph (path) at a certain x points to get the corresponding y points.

I couldn't figure a way of doing it.

Coding wisdom anyone ?

Comment: what exactly do you want to do?

Comment: Donotalo, I need to change an image intensity levels based on custom intensity curved graph.

Comment: Seems that you want to define an interpolation function, based on some (draggable?) control points. This is not really the same as constructing a path, so you might want to use an additional library for, say, cubic spline interpolation of points you provide. Have you tried a simple linear interpolation? Could this be sufficient for what you are doing with your image?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another solution is to get all the points in the `QPainterPath` by converting it to one/multiple `QPolygonF` this can be easily done like this:

```
QPainterPath path(QPointF(0,0));
path.lineTo(QPointF(100,0));
path.lineTo(QPointF(100,100));
path.lineTo(QPointF(0,100));
path.lineTo(QPointF(0,0)); 
//change this to toSubpathPolygons to get multiple polygons.
QPolygonF polygon = path.toFillPolygon();
QList<QLineF> edgeList;
for(int i=0;i < polygon.count(); i++) {
     QLineF edge;
     if(i != (polygon.count() - 1)) {
         edge.setPoints(polygon.at(i),polygon.at(i+1));
     } else {
         edge.setPoints(polygon.at(i),polygon.at(0));
     }
         edgeList<<edge;
 }
```

Then you can use a scan line to check the intersection with these edges. using the intersect function from `QLineF` and another `foreach` loop.

Answer (score 3):

```
QPainterPath p = item->path();
for(int i = 0; i < p.elementCount(); i++)
{
    QPointF pt = p.elementAt(i); //get the value of the point at index i
    p.setElementPositionAt(i, new_x, new_y); //change the value of the point at index i
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

QPainterPath doesn't have any mathematical function to compute/solve it as an equation since it's not an equation to begin with. The drawing of a path is actually paint engine specific. In a nut shell, QPainterPath is a drawing object, not even a graphing one.

The proper way of getting where you want to go is to draw the curve yourself with your own math.

But if you can live with limited precision and if your path is guaranteed to have one Y value to any possible X, then you can approximate it by rendering the QPainterPath onto a black and white QImage (as a QPainter) and scan through each line in the image to find which line has pixel X marked. The precision will depned on how big the image it is. Not perfect, but it should get you to the neighborhood. :)