# QLineSeries get value of function presented by chart by x value

Tags: c++, qt, c++14, qchart

For example I have a `QChart` with `QLineSeries` with some points. Chart plots lines between these points in view, but how can I access value of `Y` by `X` at place where no points are, i.e. if I have e.g. points `(0,0)` and `(10,10)` how can I get value of `Y` from chart for `X=5` (Y must be 5 too)?

**Update:**

I suppose that plot represents mathematical function, i.e. one `X` has exactly one `Y`.

Comment: let's say that it has the series with coordinates `QPointF(1, 1)`, `QPointF(5, 5)` and `QPointF (2, 3)` and `x = 4`, so if we intersect the QLineSeries with the line x = 4, 2 points will be obtained. of those 2 points is it returned or both?

Comment: @eyllanesc, Ok, but if we suppose that plot represents mathematical function?

Comment: Those does help [Line interpolation in Qt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18502611/line-interpolation-in-qt) , And,  [Extract points from a path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11699606/extract-points-from-a-path)