# draw cursor on a QChartView object

Tags: qt, charts, qt5

I need to draw a cursor on the QChartView object. something like this:

Cursor on the Chart

[image]

Whenever a user clicks on the chart the cursor should be moved there.
I have no idea how it is possible. As I searched It seems that this is not a built-in feature of QChartView. So How can I do it? 
BTW, I'm newbie to the QT.

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same problem. Drawing a cursor at the mouse position seems to be trivial by referring to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67596291/9758790). Note that I modify the codes from [this anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67596291/9758790) in *x.setter* from *self.update()* to *self.scene().update()*. This is important for updating the cursor. To be honest, I don't know why. You can leave a comment if you know the difference.

```
# refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/67596291/9758790
import sys
import time
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QPointF
from PyQt5.QtGui import QColor, QPainter, QPen
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
from PyQt5.QtChart import (
    QChart,
    QChartView,
    QLineSeries,
)
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class ChartView(QChartView):
    _x = None

    @property
    def x(self):
        return self._x

    @x.setter
    def x(self, x):
        self._x = x
        # self.update()
        self.scene().update()

    def drawForeground(self, painter, rect):
        if self.x is None:
            return
        painter.save()

        pen = QPen(QColor("indigo"))
        pen.setWidth(3)
        painter.setPen(pen)

        # p = self.chart().mapToPosition(QPointF(self.x, 0))
        p = QPointF(self.x, 0)
        r = self.chart().plotArea()

        p1 = QPointF(p.x(), r.top())
        p2 = QPointF(p.x(), r.bottom())
        painter.drawLine(p1, p2)

        painter.restore()

    def mousePressEvent(self, env):
        # refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/44078533/9758790
        scene_position = self.mapToScene(env.pos())
        chart_position = self.chart().mapFromScene(scene_position)
        value_at_position = self.chart().mapToValue(chart_position)
        if self.chart().axisX().min() < value_at_position.x() < self.chart().axisX().max():
            self.x = scene_position.x()


def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    series1 = QLineSeries() << QPointF(0, 3) << QPointF(1, 1) << QPointF(3, 9) << QPointF(4, 1)
    series2 = QLineSeries() << QPointF(0, 9) << QPointF(1, 8) << QPointF(3, 6) << QPointF(4, 6)
    series3 = QLineSeries() << QPointF(0, 4) << QPointF(1, 2) << QPointF(3, 2) << QPointF(4, 3)

    chart = QChart()
    chart.addSeries(series1)
    chart.addSeries(series2)
    chart.addSeries(series3)

    chart.createDefaultAxes()

    chart.legend().setVisible(True)
    chart.legend().setAlignment(Qt.AlignBottom)

    chartView = ChartView(chart)
    chartView.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)

    chartView.x = None

    window = QMainWindow()
    window.setCentralWidget(chartView)
    window.resize(420, 300)
    window.show()

    app.exec()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Which gives:

[image]

However, I find it difficult to draw the intersection point of the cursor and the line chart. As mentioned in [this forum](https://forum.qt.io/topic/115037/qchart-in-c-how-to-get-the-y-axis-value-of-more-than-one-qlineseries-at-a-time/2) and [this forum](https://forum.qt.io/topic/124549/return-interpolated-values-from-qlineseries/3), if the cursor points at the interpolated part between two data point, it is difficult to decide the y coordinates of the intersection points, because Qt doesn't provide a build-in function to get the interpolated function value at value_at_position.x(). [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49223048/9758790) is also related to find the interpolated value. So I tried to do interpolation by my self.

The following version of codes will also draw the intersection point.

```
# refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/67596291/9758790
import sys
import time
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QPointF
from PyQt5.QtGui import QColor, QPainter, QPen
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
from PyQt5.QtChart import (
    QChart,
    QChartView,
    QLineSeries,
)
from PyQt5.Qt import *
import math

class ChartView(QChartView):
    _cursor = None
    _y = []

    @property
    def cursor(self):
        return self._cursor

    @cursor.setter
    def cursor(self, point):
        # refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/44078533/9758790
        scene_position = self.mapToScene(point)
        chart_position = self.chart().mapFromScene(scene_position)
        value_at_position = self.chart().mapToValue(chart_position)
        if self.chart().axisX().min() < value_at_position.x() < self.chart().axisX().max():
            self._cursor = scene_position
            # self.update()
            self.scene().update()

    def drawForeground(self, painter, rect):
        if self.cursor is None:
            return
        painter.save()

        pen = QPen(QColor("indigo"))
        pen.setWidth(1)
        painter.setPen(pen)

        p = self.cursor
        r = self.chart().plotArea()

        p1 = QPointF(p.x(), r.top())
        p2 = QPointF(p.x(), r.bottom())
        painter.drawLine(p1, p2)

        chart_position = self.chart().mapFromScene(self.cursor)
        value_at_position = self.chart().mapToValue(chart_position)
        for series_i in self.chart().series():
            pen2 = QPen(series_i.color())
            pen2.setWidth(10)
            painter.setPen(pen2)

            # find the nearest points
            min_distance_left = math.inf
            min_distance_right = math.inf
            nearest_point_left = None
            nearest_point_right = None
            exact_point = None
            for p_i in series_i.pointsVector():
                if p_i.x() > value_at_position.x():
                    if p_i.x() - value_at_position.x() < min_distance_right:
                        min_distance_right = p_i.x() - value_at_position.x()
                        nearest_point_right = p_i
                elif p_i.x() < value_at_position.x():
                    if value_at_position.x() - p_i.x() < min_distance_right:
                        min_distance_left = value_at_position.x() - p_i.x()
                        nearest_point_left = p_i
                else:
                    exact_point = p_i
                    nearest_point_left = None
                    nearest_point_right = None
                    break
            if nearest_point_right is not None and nearest_point_left is not None:
                # do linear interpolated by my self
                k = ((nearest_point_right.y() - nearest_point_left.y()) / (nearest_point_right.x() - nearest_point_left.x()))
                point_interpolated_y = nearest_point_left.y() + k * (value_at_position.x() - nearest_point_left.x())
                point_interpolated_x = value_at_position.x()

                point_interpolated = QPointF(point_interpolated_x, point_interpolated_y)

                painter.drawPoint(self.chart().mapToScene(self.chart().mapToPosition(point_interpolated)))
            if exact_point is not None:
                painter.drawPoint(self.chart().mapToScene(self.chart().mapToPosition(exact_point)))

        painter.restore()

    def mousePressEvent(self, env):
        self.cursor = env.pos()


def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    series1 = QLineSeries() << QPointF(0, 3) << QPointF(1, 1) << QPointF(3, 9) << QPointF(4, 1)
    series2 = QLineSeries() << QPointF(0, 9) << QPointF(1, 8) << QPointF(3, 6) << QPointF(4, 6)
    series3 = QLineSeries() << QPointF(0, 4) << QPointF(1, 2) << QPointF(3, 2) << QPointF(4, 3)

    chart = QChart()
    chart.addSeries(series1)
    chart.addSeries(series2)
    chart.addSeries(series3)

    chart.createDefaultAxes()

    chart.legend().setVisible(True)
    chart.legend().setAlignment(Qt.AlignBottom)

    chartView = ChartView(chart)
    chartView.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)

    chartView.x = None

    window = QMainWindow()
    window.setCentralWidget(chartView)
    window.resize(420, 300)
    window.show()

    app.exec()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Which gives:

[image]

[This link *Track Line with Data Labels*](https://www.advsofteng.com/doc/cdcppdoc/tracklabelqt.htm) provide a solution to find a nearest data point to the mouse position and draw a line there, which avoids dealing with interpolation. My codes can also be modified to draw in this way.