# QPainterPath toFillPolygon() returns more points than the points used to draw the path itself

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qpainterpath

I have been trying to draw skeletal points of a human using 18 different joints. So, i decided to use `QGraphicsPathItem`. I could successfully generate the item which looks something like this: (pardon my drawing skills)

[image]

To achieve this i used:

```
QPainterPath pp;

pp.moveTo(m_points[0]); 
pp.lineTo(m_points[1]); 
pp.lineTo(m_points[2]); 
pp.lineTo(m_points[3]); 
pp.lineTo(m_points[4]); 

pp.moveTo(m_points[1]); 
pp.lineTo(m_points[5]); 
pp.lineTo(m_points[6]); 
pp.lineTo(m_points[7]); 

pp.moveTo(m_points[1]); 
pp.lineTo(m_points[8]); 
pp.lineTo(m_points[9]); 
pp.lineTo(m_points[10]);

pp.moveTo(m_points[1]); 
pp.lineTo(m_points[11]);
pp.lineTo(m_points[12]);
pp.lineTo(m_points[13]);

pp.moveTo(m_points[0]); 
pp.lineTo(m_points[14]);
pp.lineTo(m_points[16]);

pp.moveTo(m_points[0]); 
pp.lineTo(m_points[15]);
pp.lineTo(m_points[17]);

m_item->setPath(pp);
```

At some point of time when i wish to know the positions of the points, i use:

```
QPolygonF polygon = m_item->path().toFillPolygon();
```

this returns me 33 points instead of 18.

Is there a way to get the current positions of those 18 points i started with from the path()?

**EDIT 1:** After comparing the results of `toFillPolygon()` for an open polygon (start and end points are different) and closed polygon, i realized in an open polygon (as in my case) `toFillPolygon()` won't work or returns wrong values.

Answer (score 0):

After realizing i cannot get points from `toFillPolygon()` i stumbled on this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11699606/extract-points-from-a-path). It helped me understand we can not extract points from `QPainterPath` using `toFillPolygon()`
when our path itself is OPEN POLYGON i.e. starting and ending points are different. So, i used something like this:

```
    QVector<QPointF> pointsTable;
    QPainterPath path = m_item->path();

    pointsTable.reserve(18);

    // push the point 0 manually
    // since it is created using moveTo()
    // but we need this starting point
    pointsTable.push_back(mapToScene(path.elementAt(0)));

    // iterate through all the elements of the path
    for (int idx = 0; idx < path.elementCount(); ++idx)
    {
        // DO NOT consider moveTo() elements
        // we only need lineTo() elements
        if (!path.elementAt(idx).isMoveTo())
        {
            // push into the container
            pointsTable.push_back(mapToScene(path.elementAt(idx)));
        }
    }
```

Notice i do not consider the elements `moveTo()` but only the elements `lineTo()` except for the first `moveTo()` element which is my starting position.

So, i can get current position of all the 18 points i initially started with to draw the path.